# Why i get number of clusters less than the number of the given k?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I compute the maximal number of clusters and I get k=5. then i generate the clusters using kmeans++ and setting k=5, but i get as a result only 4 clusters. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Does it go from 0 to 4? That's 5 clusters. It's zero-based.

Comment: 4 cluster means 0,1,2,3.

Answer (score 0):

How are you currently computing the value of k?

What's likely happening is that one of your clusters is empty, causing it to disappear. This usually means that the value of k is too high for your dataset. If you lower the value of k you should find you will stop losing clusters.

I have found that some implementations of k-means++ will always give nearly identical initial centriod placement. If you need to have k=5 for some reason, you could try just using kmeans (random centroid initialisation) and see if that helps any.